# What is the following format specifier doing?

Tags: c, printf

```
         else
        {
            printf("\\%.3hho", *data);
        }
```

I could not find information regarding on how to decipher it on the net or by reading the C programming language book. I saw it in the following code snippet. The code is trying to perform password sniffing in the telnet protocol.

```
if ((pktlen - sizeof(struct ipheader)) >  dataoffset)
{
    printf("   SrcIP: %s,", inet_ntoa(ip->iph_sourceip));
    printf(" DstIP: %s,", inet_ntoa(ip->iph_destip));
    printf(" Data: ");
    u_char* data = (u_char*)tcp + dataoffset;

    for (unsigned short s = 0; s < (ntohs(ip->iph_len) - (sizeof(struct ipheader) + dataoffset)); s++)
    {
        if (isprint(*data) != 0)
        {
          printf("%c", *data);
                                  }
        else
        {
            printf("\\%.3hho", *data);
        }
        data++;
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

> Conversion specifier `o`
>
> converts a **unsigned integer** into octal representation *oooo*,
>
> *Precision* specifies the minimum number of digits to appear. <truncated>

So the string `\\%.3hho` represents a literal backslash (it's escaped), plus the format specifier `%.3hho`:

- `%...o` indicates octal representation for unsigned integer. The letter `o` also indicates the end of this specifier
- `hh` is a C99 specification, indicates `unsigned char` instead of `unsigned int`, always a single byte
- `.3` means the precision is 3, so at least 3 octal digits (000 - 377)

Comment: Is reading format specifiers from back to front a best practice ?

Comment: @Papaya-Automaton Not necessarily. The first step, however, is to determine where the format specifier ends (in my answer the `%...o` bullet point). Then because length modifiers are always letters, some people may find it easier to read them together (`ld`, `llu`, `hhx` etc.)

Comment: You can also go "forward": 1) '%' starts the format specifier, 2) '.' says that the "precision" follows, 3) '3' is the value of the precision, 4) 'h' is a length modifier, 5) the second 'h' modifies the stored length modifier, and finally 6) 'o' is the conversion specifier that closes the whole. After step 6 it is clear how to interpret the modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

The `%o` format specifier prints an unsigned value in octal.  The `hh` length modifier tells it that the value is a `char`, and the `.3` precision means that at least 3 characters will be printed.